# ejabberd refuses to start after attempting to enable mod_proxy65

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I cannot get ejabberd to start after attempting to enable mod proxy_65 with the following settings:

```
{mod_proxy65,  [
                  {host, "secusrvr.com"},
                  {ip, {0,0,0,0}},
                  {hostname, "secusrvr.com"},
                 ]},
```

I get the following syntax error, but I can't see anything wrong:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2016-05-21 12:41:44 ===
E(<0.37.0>:ejabberd_config:187) : The following lines from your configuration file might be relevant to the error:
529:   %%{mod_muc_log,[]},
530:   {mod_offline,  [{access_max_user_messages, max_user_offline_messages}]},
531:   {mod_ping,     []},
532:   %%{mod_pres_counter,[{count, 5}, {interval, 60}]},
533:   {mod_privacy,  []},
534:   {mod_private,  []},
535:   {mod_proxy65,  [
536:              {host, "secusrvr.com"},
537:              {ip, {0,0,0,0}},
538:              {hostname, "secusrvr.com"},
539:             ]},
540:   {mod_pubsub,   [
541:              {access_createnode, pubsub_createnode},
542:              {ignore_pep_from_offline, true}, % reduces resource comsumption, but XEP incompliant

=ERROR REPORT==== 2016-05-21 12:41:44 ===
E(<0.37.0>:ejabberd_config:106) : Problem loading ejabberd config file /etc/jabber/ejabberd.cfg approximately in the line 539: syntax error before: ']'
```

Answer (score 0):

You indeed have a syntax error. Your config file is wrong. Remove comma at end of line 538.